# create query with fetch

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data

I have this query:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Route p JOIN FETCH p.places pl WHERE pl.city = (:city)")
public List<Route> findByPlaces_City(@Param("city")City city);
```

It fetch me only places where places.coty = city

And what I need is:
 if any **place** from **route** have **city** like argument get that route with **fetched** all places from that route;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a query is not allowed by JPA, because you may not apply restrictions on a fetched join.

But you can simply use an inner join to apply your restriction, and another fetch join to load the cities:

```
select distinct r from Route r 
inner join r.places p
left join fetch r.places
where p.city = :city
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `left join fetch`

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Route p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.places pl WHERE pl.city = (:city)")
```

Comment: unfortunately same thing